# JAVA Lost focus fom JMenu

Tags: java, swing, focus, jmenu

This is my case, I have JMenubar and have CardLayout. In fact that I use JMenu to move for each card, so JMenus don't have any JMenuItem(It's some weird, huh?). I set for a button show a message, for example. The trouble is when I click on a JMenu, then click button. It don't show message right away until I click on the button 2 times. I thinked it's about the focus and try to use button.requestFocusInWindow(). But it's fail. So, I need somebody help me?

Comment: use JMenu.getModel() from ChongeListener, test if isArmed, isSelected or isPressed, but I think there must be another notifier(s), otherwise post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable cause a.mm. issue with focusing Jmenu on 2nd. mouse event

Comment: start with MenuListener or MenuSelectionManager with Swing Action

Comment: you are mis-using the JMenu: they meant as containers for menuItems, not as stand-alone menuItems (the hierarchy is a bit hazy, though). Don't, you'll confuse your users. Instead, consider using a JToolBar.

Answer (score 0):

package Temp;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PopupMenuDemo2 extends JFrame{
    public static Container createContentPane() {
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("click");
        button.setSize(80, 80);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("button's clicked");
            }
        });
        contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        contentPane.add(button);

        return contentPane;
    }

    public static JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar;
        JMenu menu1;
        JMenu menu2;

        //Create the menu bar.
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //Build the first menu.
        menu1 = new JMenu("A Menu");
        menuBar.add(menu1);

        //Build second menu in the menu bar.
        menu2 = new JMenu("Another Menu");
        menu2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("mouse press on menu2");
            }
        });
        menuBar.add(menu2);
        return menuBar;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        PopupMenuDemo2 pmn2 = new PopupMenuDemo2();
        pmn2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create/set menu bar and content pane.
        pmn2.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
        pmn2.setContentPane(createContentPane());

        //Display the window.
        pmn2.setSize(450, 260);
        pmn2.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.

        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
//        try {
//            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
//                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
//                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
//                    break;
//                }
//            }
//        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
//            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PopupMenuDemo2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
//            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PopupMenuDemo2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
//            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PopupMenuDemo2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
//            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PopupMenuDemo2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//        }
        //</editor-fold>

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I find the reason. But I really don't understand. This doesn't work when I uncomment the `final try-catch statement Set Look And Feel`. Otherwise, It's done what I wish. Still I need to know something clearly?